# Sending object from form (request - image)

Tags: asp.net, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have situation where I need to send [FromForm] file to swagger, and I don't know how can I do this from WPF, any kind of help will be welcome, please some examples in comments. Thank you very much on helping

Comment: In what form is the api expecting the file? Can you share the api description of the upload action?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Task<IActionResult> UploadFileAsMessageDto([FromForm]FileUploadDto fileUploadDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)




public class FileUploadDto
    {
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }